# 18.10 Switch User Closes Running Applications

Tags: users, 18.10, switch-user

I couldn't find a thread properly addresses the issue that I am seeing, so I am asking here.

Ubuntu Gnome 18.10 fresh install less than 24 hours ago. Updated the system. Installed various applications (Chrome, Remmina, Sublime, etc.) and the system has been working fine.

Added a new user (admin) to the system to separate out personal from work user spaces. Logged in as the new user and set up the preferences to my liking. All good so far.

For this next part, that is the issue here, it does not matter which user is logged in, or from which user the switch is initiated.
When I switch users the applications for the user I just came *from* are closed when I return back to that user. I switch back again, and all applications are again closed. This defeats the purpose of "switching users".

Is there a bug on this? If so I cannot find it to contribute. Is there a workaround?

System Specs:
Intel NUC8i5BEH
Integrated Intel graphics
WD Black NVMe
32 GB RAM

Comment: I know I'm not providing value here, but this is happening to me in Ubuntu 23.10 in 2023. Hoping you found a solution or to revive this thread. Thanks!